# SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

Tags: php, json

```
<?php

session_start();
header('Content-type: application/json');

$email = "XXXX"; 
$password = "XXX"; 
$serviceId = 4728;

$url = 'https://login.globo.com/api/authentication';

$jsonAuth = array(
'captcha' => '',
'payload' => array(
 'email' => $email,
 'password' => $password,
 'serviceId' => $serviceId
    )
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($jsonAuth));
$result = curl_exec($ch);
$obj=json_decode($result);
echo "id: " . $obj->{'glbId'};

?>
```

Meu código é esse, quando executo no navegador aparece o erro: `SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data`

Alguém pode ajudar?

Answer (score 2):

É só você tirar o `header('Content-type: application/json');` o navegador esta achando que o seu conteúdo é `JSON` e tenta formatar.

Answer (score 0):

vc não precisa de chaves para acessar o objeto. 
Assim:

`$obj->glbId;`

Comment: Obrigado. Consegui

Comment: Tassio você pode por favor marcar a resposta como correta, só assim você sinaliza que a pergunta foi respondida.